# How to turn a string into a floating point number in ATS?

Tags: ats

Basically, I am looking for a function of the following type:

```
fun string2double(rep: string): double
```

which converts a string representing a floating point number into the number.

For instance, `string2double("3.14")` should return `3.14`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented as follows:

```
fun string2double(x: string): double = g0string2float_double(x)
```